# Wrong cookie value being set from laravel API after migrating to AWS

Tags: reactjs, laravel, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I just migrated my Laravel 9 API and ReactJS frontend from a VPS to AWS. The API is hosted on a Elastic Beanstalk/EC2 Instance and my ReactJS frontend is on S3 with CloudFront. Both are using Route53 with their domains api.domain.app and domain.app and SSLs. Everything is working except a refresh token that is stored in a httpOnly cookie. This all worked correctly on my previous VPS server.

I set the cookie in CloudFront to be passed through in the headers but the problem is that the cookie value is wrong. The value of the cookie is the same every time it is set, which is not what it is suppose to do.

I'm setting the cookie in my login function in laravel when a remember me box is checked.

```
// Creating and setting cookie values
$cookie = Cookie::create('token-name')
        ->withValue($refresh)
        ->withExpires(strtotime("+6 months"))
        ->withSecure(true)
        ->withHttpOnly(true)
        ->withDomain("domain.app")
        ->withSameSite("none");

// Login functions return appending the cookie to the response
return response($response, 201)->cookie($cookie);
```

The cookie is set with all the correct settings except value. I've tried changing the withValue variable $refresh with 'test' but that made no change.

It is working in Postman but not in the browser. The only other change is that I was running react in dev mode on the VPS under port 3000 where as now I'm doing dev in localhost and pushing changes through GIT and CodePipeline. Just to clarify I did not have the build on the VPS only the dev running.

I'm guessing the issue is something with not running on port 3000 anymore and using the actual build on the live server.

What am I missing? What is happening and how do I fix it? Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake on my part. I forgot to update the stateful domains in the sanctum config file.